# Use single Template for multiple Item Sources and render separate combobox in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am new to WPF/XAML so I am stuck in one problem is it possible that if I create one TEMPLATE of combobox in UI and what if is it possible to use one `ComboBox` to render multi-item sources? For example, I have two item sources A and B and in XAML I have one common template. So is it possible that I can create two different `ComboBox` in UI for A and B from single template?

I am using below template for creation

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboboxtemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding CboItemsource}" SelectedItem="{Binding comboboxSelecteditem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Visibility="{Binding ShowCombobox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="{Binding ComboboxWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding FieldValueIsEditable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Description">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" Width="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text= "{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. WPF offers several different mechanisms for reuse of XAML elements. It seems most likely that your scenario is best addressed by defining a `<Style TargetType="ComboBox"/>`, but other options include making a `UserControl` or `DataTemplate`, both of which also allow reuse of XAML elements. You should simplify _and_ elaborate your example, so that you've provided a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and illustrating exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: As per my understanding, You want to use DataTemplate 
in multiple combobox right?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a style that you apply to both `ComboBoxes`, .e.g.:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="cmbStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ShowCombobox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding FieldValueIsEditable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTextSearchEnabled" Value="True" />
            <!-- ... -->
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" Width="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text= "{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>

        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" ItemsSource="{Binding CboItemsource}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding comboboxSelecteditem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Style="{StaticResource cmbStyle}" />

        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb2" ItemsSource="{Binding OtherItemsource}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding OtherSelecteditem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Style="{StaticResource cmbStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```